# Calculating the power of sine wave

Tags: power

If there is a sine wave,its voltage (peak amplitude)is 5V,current is 1A,and its period is 5m.Is its power \$ \frac{\frac{5}{\sqrt2}*\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}{0.005}\$ or \$\frac{5}{\sqrt2}*\frac{1}{\sqrt2}*0.005\$ watts?i am a little confused now.

Comment: What does dimensional analysis tell you?

Comment: "*its voltage is 5V*", what **exactly** do you mean by this? Are you talking about the [amplitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude) of the sine wave? Or the [RMS value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) of the sine wave?

Comment: @ThePhoton oh how I wish that dimensional analysis be taught at high school level sometimes...would save me a lot of trouble!

Comment: @SimonMarcoux That, and the difference between power and energy should be mandatory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

theory analysis,
power equals to the integration of the voltage with the current over a fixed period 
[image]

Comment: In case of a DC offset (or unbalance), the integration limit may need to be extended to T.

Comment: yes u are right！

Answer (score 1):

Power of a sine wave is not dependent on the period (or frequency for that matter). It is only computed from the root mean square (RMS) value of your sine wave and the phase difference between current and voltage. RMS value is given by dividing the peak value of a signal (voltage for example) by the square root of 2. For simplicity, it is often much simpler to multiply by 0.707 (the decimal value of 1/sqrt(2))

Assuming that your voltage and amp value are peak values (maximum of the sine input). This will yield the following power: 5V * 0.707 * 1A * 0.707 = 2.5W. However, keep in mind that this assumes that both the current and voltage are AC in nature with no phase shifting and at the exact same frequency (which for first approximation is most often good enough).

Depending on where you live, AC power of your house is already expressed in RMS value (e.g Canada is 120V at 60hz) Peak value is therefore about 180 volts.

Comment: so it is not have relation with time for calculating the power

Comment: You could indeed compute an instantaneous power value if you know both functions: v(t) and i(t). Power will simply be p = v(t)*(it). But, most of the time, you don't even need to consider this. If the load is not purely resistive, you will have a phase shift between the current and the voltage. At the house level, it is often not significant enough to be taken into account, but it is quite significant at the industry level. That however is slightly beyond the scope of your current question.

Comment: Power (t) is instantaneous, Energy takes time.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt I was opposing steady state RMS power consumption which is constant and analogically similar to an average versus instantaneous point by point power consumption which vary wildly like the underlying sine waves. You are however quite right that you can include a time variable and be able to compute how much Energy was drained by that device.

Comment: Of course the averaged RMS is done for 1 cycle

Answer (score 1):

Power depends on the load across which you have applied the signal.The load here is 5 ohms. For a periodic AC signal:

$$P = \frac{V_{rms}^2}{R}=V_{rms}.I_{rms} = I_{rms}^2R $$

Since the applied signal is a sin wave:
$$(V_{rms},I_{rms}) = (\frac{V_m}{\sqrt 2},\frac{I_m}{\sqrt 2})$$
$$\therefore P = 2.5W$$